# ten-digit codes combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many ten-digit codes can be made in which each digit occurs exactly once, but in which the following patterns do not occur:

(a) 123 (e.g., 1203987654 may, but 9876501234 may not)

(b) 123 and 98765 (e.g. 3210567489 is allowed, but the two examples given earlier are not. may not).

(c) 123, 98765, and 04 (e.g., you may use 8412765930, but all of the previously given examples may not).

I have:

(a) 10! -8!

(b) 10! -8! -6! +4!

(c) 10! - (8! +6! +9! -4! -7! -5! +3!)

Can someone please confirm these solutions/explain why a solution is incorrect?

Comment: In part (c), it is not possible to have both the strings 98765 and 48.  Is there a typographical error in the statement of the problem?

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question.

Comment: With the edit, it is correct.

Comment: Did you mean $04$ in part (c)?  Otherwise, the same problem occurs as before.

Comment: Let me please understand you, in the second part you do not want 123 to be in your string, neither also 98765 right? So 1234567890 is invalid and so does the following two 1239876540 and 9876543210

Comment: Your solutions are correct.  That said, had you made an error, it would have been easier to spot if you had explained your reasoning.  For instance, in part (a), you could have said that you were subtracting those cases in which 123 did occur from the total number of objects and that if you treat 123 as a single object, then you have eight objects to permute, the block containing 123 and the other seven numbers.  In parts (b) and (c), you could have explained that you were applying the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.